# Is using SnapKit causing memory leaks

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting, snapkit

I am using `SnapKit` to handle my `AutoLayout`. I am wondering does this code cause a memory leak because I am capturing self in a closure?

```
writtenUpSwitch.snp.makeConstraints {
    $0.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
    $0.centerY.equalTo(writtenUpLabel.snp.centerY)
}
```

This line `$0.centerY.equalTo(writtenUpLabel.snp.centerY)` is accessing `UILabel` in a closure without using `[weak self]` In another of instance this will cause a memory Leak

Comment: No, because the closure is nonescaping

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, it doesn't.

The reason is mentioned in the comment under the original question – the closure is not `@escaping`, it means it's not retained or captured by the closure to be dispatched somewhen later and it's dispatched in the same execution stack where it's allocated (like `map:`, `compactMap:` and etc).

When you're working with closures and captured values you should pay attention not only to `self` being retained by the closure. It's important to consider a potential retain cycles caused by any variable.

Here's an example:

```
let objectDependency = SomeObjectDependency()
let object = SomeObject(dependency: objectDependency) /// dependency is retained here

objectDependency.someAsyncFunc(withCompletion block: @escaping () -> ()) { in
   object.doSomeSomething() /// here we have a retain cycle!
}
```

The problem here is not trivial, because we have no `self` involved in the closure. The cycle here is caused by retain chain `object` -> `objectDependency` -> `closure` -> `object`.